# How to take derivative when the function is also parameterized

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Why 
$$ \frac{\partial f_\tau(X_\tau)}{\partial \tau} =
\left .\frac{\partial f_\tau}{\partial \tau}\right|_{X = X_\tau}
+ f'_\tau(X_\tau) \frac{\partial X_\tau}{\partial \tau} $$
where $f_\tau$ is a function. For example, 
$$ f_\tau(X) = \sum_{i=0}^d{ a_i X^i } $$

Could anyone help to take its derivative or tell which material to refer to?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to consider $f_\tau (X) = f(\tau,X)$. Then the chain rule applies:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} f_\tau(X_\tau) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} f(\tau,X_\tau) + \frac{\partial}{\partial X}f(\tau,X_\tau) \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}X_\tau.
$$